# nginx rewrite URL only if the original one gives 404 error

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I've this rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/full_(.*)$ http://www.domain.tdl/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/$1 permanent;
```

It redirects every request of images which starts with `full_` to the same image without the prefix.

Now I'd like to apply this rule only if the requested image does not exists (404 error).

How can I do?

Comment: You mean, you want redirect only if there is no file `components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/full_....`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `try_files` with named location that will do redirect:

```
location /components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/full_ {
    try_files $uri @redirect;
}

location @redirect {
    rewrite ^(/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/)full_(.*)$ http://www.domain.tdl$1$2 permanent;
}
```

Comment: sorry just did some more check and it does not work :\

Comment: fixed, I have to add `^~ ` before the location path.